# Javascript binary data converted to weird "[Object]" on POST to server

Tags: javascript, forms, kotlin, object, server

I have a small JS/HTML front-end where i want to be able to send files to a kotlin backend server. The problem I am having at the moment seems like it is a wierd type like convertsion done by javascript.

> note: this is code will not to be actually used but more of a learning experiance with server and file system management. For this reason i also dont want to use something like the FormData() object of javascript though i am fine with using Blob.

the problem lies with the JS part :

```js
const parts = files.map((file) => {
    return file.fileData;
 });
```

When i use the code above everything would work fine, but I only send the actual binary of the file not the extra information like size or a separator. When I try to add something like a string or any other object as far as i have tested like so:

```js
 const parts = files.map((file) => {
    return file.fileData + "---";
  });
```

The code instead of sending the binary, will just send this:

`[object File]---[object File]---[object File]---`

> This is not any type of special syntax that I have used. That is the actual String it sends over (I've just copy and pasted).

Below is all the code i am using:

**FRONT END**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>File and Folder Upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
      <h1>File and Folder Upload</h1>
      <input
        type="file"
        id="folder"
        name="folder[]"
        directory=""
        webkitdirectory=""
        mozdirectory=""
      />
      <button onclick="uploadFiles()">Upload</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

JASCRIPT

```js
function uploadFiles() {
  const folderInput = document.getElementById("folder");
  var files = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < folderInput.files.length; i++) {
    const file = folderInput.files[i];
    files.push({
      length: file.size,
      fileName: file.name,
      fileData: file,
    });
  }

  const parts = files.map((file) => {
    return file.fileData;
  });

  var blob = new Blob(parts);

  fetch("http://localhost:8000/upload", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
    body: blob,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("Files uploaded successfully");
        response.text().then((data) => {
          console.log("Return body data: ", data);
        });
      } else {
        console.error("Error uploading files");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    });

  return false;
}
```

**BACKEND Kotlin**

```kotlin
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.File

class MyServer {
    private lateinit var server: HttpServer

    fun startServer() {
        try {
            server = HttpServer.create(InetSocketAddress(8000), 0)
            server.createContext("/upload", PutRemoteFiles())
            server.executor = null
            server.start()
            val host = server.address
            println("Server started at http://$host")
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            println("Error starting the server: ${e.message}")
        }
    }

    fun stopServer() {
        server.stop(0)
        println("Server stopped")
    }

    private class PutRemoteFiles : HttpHandler {
        override fun handle(exchange: HttpExchange) {
            // Set CORS headers
            val headers = exchange.responseHeaders
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST")
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")

            if (exchange.requestMethod == "POST") {
                try {
                    val requestBody = exchange.requestBody
                    val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(requestBody))
                    val formData = reader.readText()
                    writeBinFile(formData)
                    val response = "Received form data: $formData"
                    exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length.toLong())
                    val os: OutputStream = exchange.responseBody
                    os.write(response.toByteArray())
                    os.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    println("Error reading the request body: ${e.message}")
                    exchange.sendResponseHeaders(500, 0)
                    exchange.responseBody.close()
                }
            } else {
                val response = "Invalid request"
                exchange.sendResponseHeaders(400, response.length.toLong())
                val os: OutputStream = exchange.responseBody
                os.write(response.toByteArray())
                os.close()
            }
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    val server = MyServer()
    server.startServer()
    println("Server started. Type 'stop' to stop the server.")
    var command = readLine()
    while (command != "stop") {
        command = readLine()
    }
    server.stopServer()
}

fun writeBinFile(file: String) {
    val fileName = "DataBase/output.bin"
    val content = file.toByteArray()
    try {
        val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(fileName)
        fileOutputStream.write(content)
        fileOutputStream.close()
        println("File '$fileName' is written successfully.")
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        println("An error occurred while writing the file: ${e.message}")
    }
}
```

Comment: `file.fileData + "---"` will cause `file.fileData` to be coerced to a string, and the default `.toString()` method on objects returns the string "[object <type>]". The <type> in your case is "File".

Comment: Consider using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects). Use [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) to add another section to the request. You can e.g add a file of type `Blob` or `File`. But you cannot mix as this will result in the binary data being converted into a string which does not make sense. From the docs `append()`s `value` parameter: `The field's value. This can be a string or Blob (including subclasses such as File). If none of these are specified the value is converted to a string.`

Comment: By the way, you can simply pass an instance of `FormData` as the `body` parameter of a fetch request, and `fetch()` will set the conent-type etc. for you automatically.

Comment: @Mushroomator please look at the note I have in my post. Also adding a string to a object should, when looked at a lower level not be a problem because both are still binary data regardless of the fancy type conversions that happen in javascipt.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this by repasenting everything as binary data so that javascript never needs to use type conversions that could never return a `[object Type]`.

This was done using the File API and a binary array like so:

```js
function uploadFiles() {
  const folderInput = document.getElementById("folder");
  const files = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < folderInput.files.length; i++) {
    const file = folderInput.files[i];
    files.push({
      length: file.size,
      fileName: file.name,
      fileData: file,
    });
  }

  function readAsBinary(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        resolve(reader.result);
      };
      reader.onerror = reject;
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    });
  }

  Promise.all(files.map((file) => readAsBinary(file.fileData)))
    .then((binaryDataArray) => {
      // Combine the binary data arrays with the delimiter
      let combinedBinary = new Uint8Array();
      binaryDataArray.forEach((binaryData, index) => {
        const fileInfo = `---------${files[index].fileName}---------${files[index].length}---------
`;
        const fileInfoArray = new TextEncoder().encode(fileInfo);
        combinedBinary = new Uint8Array([...combinedBinary, ...fileInfoArray]);
        combinedBinary = new Uint8Array([
          ...combinedBinary,
          ...new Uint8Array(binaryData),
        ]);
      });

      const blob = new Blob([combinedBinary]);

      fetch("http://localhost:8000/upload", {
        method: "POST",
        body: blob,
      })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            console.log("Files uploaded successfully");
            response.text().then((data) => {
              console.log("Return body data: ", data);
            });
          } else {
            console.error("Error uploading files");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error reading files:", error);
    });
}
```

> the TextEncoder was also a used
>
> ```js
> const fileInfoArray = new TextEncoder().encode(fileInfo);
> ```
>
> converts to a `Uint8Array` so it stays the same type and not a
> `[object String]`

Comment: I would have created a solution that dose not necessary need to read the content of the file or be required to parse a boundary. FormData payload is very historical and not so good. something that's better is something that is randomly accessible and searchable. meaning it would be better to have a central directory (header) that describes how large all files are and where the start/end is starting.  similar to zip, tar, or other archive formats. i did role my own version a long time before: https://gist.github.com/jimmywarting/b6e34e018ba31a72068409821ce94ca9#the-solution

Comment: @Endless Thank you, That Github Post was really good and explained a lot. It is indeed a better solution that what i am doing right now. I will, for sure end up using something similar when I try to make a version 2.0 of this.

Comment: I just added an alternative solution to my gist that utilize json instead. see: https://gist.github.com/jimmywarting/b6e34e018ba31a72068409821ce94ca9?permalink_comment_id=4638320#gistcomment-4638320